What am I missing in deriving the dual of this soft margin support vector machine?
I am trying to derive the dual form of a support vector machine from its primal form (see top of section "Kernel SVM").
While missing from the formulation linked above, I've proceeded thus far assuming the $ξ$ variables should be included in the set of variables the primal minimizes over, as I believe $C$ is a hyperparameter but the $ξ$ variables are parameters to be tweaked by the classifier (further evidenced by formulations from other sources which also minimize over $ξ$).  I decided to start with the special case with $2$ features and $2$ training data points to see everything unpacked, and then maybe repeat the process using more general notation.  So the primal I started with is...$$\min\limits_{w_1, w_2, b, ξ_1, ξ_2}\ w_1 ^2 + w_2 ^2 + Cξ_1 + Cξ_2 \\ s.t.\ \ \ y_1 (w_1 {x_{feature 1}}_{_{point 1}} + w_2 {x_{feature 2}}_{_{point 1}} + b) \geq 1 - ξ_1 \\ y_2 (w_1 {x_{feature 1}}_{_{point 2}} + w_2 {x_{feature 2}}_{_{point 2}} + b) \geq 1 - ξ_2 \\ ξ_1 \geq 0 \\ ξ_2 \geq 0$$...where everything is a scalar (no vectors).  The Lagrangian should be...$$\mathcal L = w_1 ^2 + w_2 ^2 + Cξ_1 + Cξ_2 - \alpha_1 (y_1 (w_1 {x_{feature 1}}_{_{point 1}} + w_2 {x_{feature 2}}_{_{point 1}} + b) - 1 + ξ_1)\ -\ \alpha_2 (y_2 (w_1 {x_{feature 1}}_{_{point 2}} + w_2 {x_{feature 2}}_{_{point 2}} + b) - 1 + ξ_2)$$Copying this step, the original problem gets replaced by $\max\limits_{\alpha_1 \geq 0, \alpha_2 \geq 0}\ [\min\limits_{w_1, w_2, b, ξ_1, ξ_2} \mathcal L]$.  To solve the inner minimization, I set the gradient of the Lagrangian to the zero vector and get the system...$$w_1 = \frac{\alpha_1 y_1 {x_{feature 1}}_{_{point 1}} + \alpha_2 y_2 {x_{feature 1}}_{_{point 2}}}{2} \\ w_2 = \frac{\alpha_1 y_1 {x_{feature 2}}_{_{point 1}} + \alpha_2 y_2 {x_{feature 2}}_{_{point 2}}}{2} \\ \alpha_1 y_1 = -\alpha_2 y_2 \\ \alpha_1 = C \\ \alpha_2 = C$$...but there is not enough information in this system to substitute $b$, $ξ_1$, or $ξ_2$ out of the Lagrangian.  How can I proceed?  Was it incorrect to minimize over $ξ_1$ and $ξ_2$ in the primal?  I don't see how treating them as constants would fix this issue.  Also, did I write the Lagrangian correctly?  The main thing I'm unsure of is whether I need to subtract another $ξ_1$ and $ξ_2$ from the Lagrangian to account for the nonnegativity constraints in the primal, but my hunch was that these constraints are simply not included in the Lagrangian representation.
